Astrogator sequence scripting tool
TIA: In STK, I'm building an astrogator sequence for a finite burn with a string seeding in the main sequence. I've come across a problem that when operator inputs string and doesn't check timing, if the start time of the maneuver is before the end time of the last maneuver, 'spagetification' occurs (basically the propagator goes all the way past the time of the scenario and just does loads of lines to try to propagate to the requested time that was before the end of the last burn). The simple answer is not to let operators do that, but I want to write in the scripting tool a way to use a return sequence in the nested sequence to stop the progress if the initial nested propagate sequence violates the constraints of the end of the last sequence. Please help.
